# GIMP Clone using different size, rotation, reflection, perspective transforms?

Tags: gimp, tools, transform, plugin

Is there a plugin for GIMP to enable cloning with transforms (size, rotation, reflection and/or perspective) performed automatically?

Currently, the only way I can see to do these things is to duplicate, transform & re-select the clone source each time, which is rather onerous if a new transform is required frequently. (Also, the "Perspective Clone" tool does not behave as required i.e. transform a flat image into a perspective.)

I have searched, but found nothing useful. I am considering learning python-fu just to write such a plugin myself, but won't bother if one is already available.

Thanks!

Comment: The perspective clone tool is not for transforming a flat shape into perspective, it's for cloning objects that are already in perspective, specifically to maintain the perspective of the object being cloned. [See example here](https://imgur.com/AhcxLuR).

Answer (score 1):

[ofn-rotate-layer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) will produce multiple copies of a layer.

A problem with perspective is to be able to specify it in a humanly understandable way, and define what it means to apply it several times.

Likewise, how do you apply flip more than once, since when you flip twice you are back to the original?

Comment: Thanks for the link - it's definitely a start and some nice example scripts in that list. What I'm after is a method of quickly specifying these transforms from a dialog which will apply them to a temporary image from the same source image each time so that i) integrity isn't lost after each transform, and ii) I don't have to duplicate + manually transform, then switch back to clone mode after each stroke.    Don't know anything of the GIMP API, but I'm assuming there's some way to leverage the existing perspective tools to define the desired perspective.  I'll keep investigating, thanks!